# Prove that the vector space of real convergent power series does not have a countable basis

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, analysis, hamel-basis

Define $V$ as the subset of $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$, the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of formal power series with real coefficients, such that
for any $f\in V$, for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$, the series $f$ always converges when evaluated at $r$.
It can be shown that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$.

I am trying to show that $V$ does not have a countable basis.
Suppose for contradiction that $S$ is a countable basis of $V$.
Write the $i$th element in $S$ as $f_i:=\sum_j a_{ij}x^j$.
One attempt to construct an element $g$ in $V$ such that $g$ is not spanned by $S$
would be some kind of diagonal argument, i.e. $g:=\sum_j h(a_{jj})x^j$ for some suitable function $h$.
However, I struggle to find an $h$ such that $g$ is convergent
because the $a_{jj}$ can be quite arbitrary.
Is there any other promising way I can do this?

Comment: Isn't it enough to just remark that the $x + a$, for $j \in \mathbb N$ and $a \in \mathbb R$, are in $V$ ? Clearly it is linearly independent and uncountable.

Comment: @Falcon $-2x+(x+1)+(x-1)=0$

Comment: @Falcon You have $(x+1)-(x+2)-(x+3)+(x+4)=0$

Comment: Okay yes my bad, but what if $a \in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @Falcon It's the same. The linearly independent set $\{1,x\}$ spans the same space as what's spanned by $\{x+a\}$, so this space has dimension 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subspace $U\subset V$ consisting of all  functions of the form $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {c_n\over n!}x^n$$ where $c=\{c_n\}\in\ell^\infty.$ The space $U$ is isomorphic to $\ell^\infty,$ hence it does not admit a countable basis, as an infinite dimensional Banach space. Therefore $V$ does not admit such a basis.